# CMake toolchain file: Appropriate value of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` for embedded development

Tags: c++, cmake, arm, embedded, toolchain

After trying to read the documentation and read other examples on the internet I landed on specifying the following variables for embedded CMake.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
#set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR cortex-m3)
```

I have tried both `arm` and `cortex-m3` as the value supplied to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`, but I'm still having to manually identify the architecture to the compile using the following flags.

```
add_compile_options(
    -mcpu=cortex-m3
    -mthumb
)
```

I would have expected these seemingly obvious flags to be abstracted by CMake, and picked up by specifying the value of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`.

Am I messing up something obvious, or should I be utilizing different variables in my CMake toolchain file?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong. All arm processors are different.

Just as an example here are some hardware options an arm core could have:

- Thumb-1 instructions
- Thumb-2 instructions
- hardware multiply (32/32/32 and 32/32/64)
- divide
- dsp
- single precision floating point hardware
- double precision floating point hardware
- trust zone
- copprocessors
- and many more...

So there doesn't exist a single arm core, let alone an M3 one, it differs per implementation of the hardware manufacturer.

As such you'll have to specify the compiler options for your arm core.